# jQuery loop + update payload

Tags: jquery

My Data is:

- Hanson
- Raisa

  123456789
  987654321

I am trying to send through:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "**Webhook link goes here**;

  $("p").each(function(index, sendNumber) {

$("li").each(function(index, sendMessage) {

  var payload = {
    "intent": "message",
    "data": {
      "toNumber": ($(sendNumber).text()),
      "text": ($(sendMessage).text())
    }
  };
  $.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), function(data) {})
})
  });
})
```

Currently it sends the data, however sends both informations to both people.

Answer (score 0):

This checks the li elements within each p.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "**Webhook link goes here**;

  $("p").each(function(index, sendNumber) {
    $(this).find("li").each(function(index, sendMessage) {

  var payload = {
    "intent": "message",
    "data": {
      "toNumber": ($(sendNumber).text()),
      "text": ($(sendMessage).text())
    }
  };
  $.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), function(data) {})
})
  });
})
```